# Logcat is not showing log for device, but log is showing for emulator eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I am trying to run app with my device Nexus 5X, Its running let me show the screen shot before running

[image: before running the app]

DDMS View

[image]

The log for my device Nexus 5x is not coming, then i tried it with One plus 3, For that the log is coming.

One more thing to mention is that the emulator i am using is also nexus 5x 6.0

my device is nexus 5X 7.0

one plus 3 is also 6.0

And take a look at my sdk manager

there are there items installed

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: The logcat format on binary level has been changed and Eclipse can not read it. You can no longer use it. However you can still use `adb logcat`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pain in the ass, but eclipse was deprecated as Android dev environment, so you should swap to Android Studio probably thats the reason youre not seeing logcat, because eclipse plugin stopped receiving updates 3 years ago and your probably using some of the recent API versions.

Comment: the problem is that the project i am using is not compatible with android studio

Comment: holy moly, sorry pal i started with android studio, theres nothing i can do for you except wishing you good luck :/

Comment: @Mukund: Conversion of a project from Eclipse to Android Studio often does not work out-of-the-box. But with a little "clean-up" it can be done.

Comment: @Robert is there any tutorials for this?

Comment: @Mukund Heres the [best advice](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html?hl=es-419) for the migration, although depending on the project it could change a lot